# Thread-safe timezone-specific time display in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, time

I have a multi-threaded application which needs to display certain dates to the user. The dates are stored using UTC Unix time values. However, the date must be displayed in the time zone of the user, not the local server time or UTC. Basically, I need a function like this:

```
struct tm *usertime_r(const time_t *timer, struct tm *result, const int timezone) {
  <just like localtime_r, except it uses UTC+timezone as the timezone>
}
```

This function must be thread safe, so I don't believe that setting the `TZ` environment variable would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the user's offset-from-UTC in seconds, you can just add/subtract that from the `time_t` and pass the result to `gmtime_r`.

For example, Australian Eastern Daylight Time is +11, which means you'd add `(11*3600)` to the time value.

Comment: This is a very, very basic answer and is not actually possible for many time zones, as the system libraries do not accurately track many changes.  Just an offset is not enough as it changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary to caf's answer, the `<tzinfo.h>` header can be used to get the offset-from-UTC for a given timezone.  The public domain timezone database contains tons of information; on Linux distros I've used, it's browseable in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, and I believe Apple packages it with iTunes for Win32.

From the command line on most distros, you can do this:

```
# it's easy to find out what timezones are available
$ file /usr/share/zoneinfo/{US/Eastern,UTC}
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern: timezone data
/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC:        timezone data

# now examine them
$ zdump US/Eastern UTC
US/Eastern  Wed Dec 23 00:11:31 2009 EST
GMT         Wed Dec 23 05:11:31 2009 UTC
```

Looks like US/Eastern is currently in standard time (it would print `EDT` during the summer), and that it's 5 hours before UTC, which gives you your offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Do you have a link for <tzinfo.h> ? All I can find with Google is Python and Ruby libraries. It feels a bit like "the long way round" to have to run an external program to get back a string which I then have to parse, all just to find out how far New York is from UTC at the moment. :-(